# Series expansion of exponential form

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the simplified results of $1+e^{j\theta}+e^{j2\theta}+\cdots+e^{jM\theta}$ as $M$ goes to infinity?
First it looks like Taylore series expansion of the x to the power $2,3,\ldots$ but as the $e^{j\theta}$ is a complex number and $e$ by itself is a number bigger than $1$ I am not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that by [**geometric series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) for $e^{j\theta}\neq 1$

$$1+e^{j\theta}+e^{j2\theta}+...+e^{jM\theta}=\frac{1-e^{j(M+1)\theta}}{1-e^{j\theta}}$$

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a "hint" as much as it is "telling the answer" lol

Comment: The expansion is not valid if $\theta = \pi$

Comment: @Jam Yes you are right! I gave too much information here for a hint.

Comment: @Eval Yes you are right, I add that!Thanks

Comment: Also, note that if $\theta = \pi$, the sequence so generated is itself divergent. So.

Comment: @Eval We need that $\theta \neq 2k\pi$ for the summation given, why are you referring to $\theta \neq k\pi$?

Comment: So this would be for a limited number of M. I see that if M goes to infinity , it doesn't make any difference as the angel will just rotate. Am I right?

Comment: @SaraH, yeah exactly. The series will be convergent for any value except, $\theta = k\pi$. Otherwise, the series will be divergent.

Comment: @SaraH Yes exactly the series never converges indeed |z|=1.